# JSP document with highlight in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ide

Is it a easy way to let Visual Studio handle JSP files and highlight the HTML that it recognise and ignore the rest? Simply I want to run the JSP files thru VS HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

**Tools** > **Options** > **Text Editor** from the list on the left > **File Extension**

Add the JSP extension and use HTML editor.